# (C#) XNA 4.0 StencilBuffer access

Tags: c#, xna, render, target

When I'm using StencilBuffer during drawing operations to render targets, is there any way I can see during debugging what the stencil buffer contains? I'm searching for hours now, and either I'm missing something totaly obvious, I can't find a way to look this table up.

There was a property DepthStencilBuffer in the GraphicsDevice in XNA 3.1, but it's not there anymore. Now we tell if we want to use stencil Buffer when we create Render Targets, yes, but how can I access the Stencil Buffer after that, so I can see if I have values in Stencil Buffer that I expect?

cheers
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a comment for this normally, but I don't have enough rep for it yet...

I would recommend reading through this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Shawn Hargreaves explains that the uses for Stencil Buffers are insignificant and can be done using other techniques that yield similar performance.

One of the quotes from that page:

> **Question:**
>
> For depth buffers, what about situation such as:
>
> 1) Depth pre pass + normalss to colour channel
>
> 2) other stuff... (eg AO)
>
> 3) render solid objects using depth buffer from before and a new render target. (also reads things like AO)
>
> 4) use depth buffer again for another pass(eg volume fog)
>
> **Answer:**
>
> The biggest restriction of the new API is that you cannot share a single depth buffer across multiple different rendertargets. However, it is usually possible to achieve this kind of rendering architecture (on Windows, anyway) just by arranging things so that any time you want to reuse the depth buffer, you are drawing to the same rendertarget.
>
> For instance, the classic deferred shading optimization of using depth/stencil to cull light volumes is totally doable: you just need to arrange your buffer operations so that these light accumulation passes are done into the same rendertarget that was bound on index #0 during the initial scene rendering.